# Expected Unqualified-ID Before 'do'(and 'while')

Tags: programming

I am getting the error "error: expected unqualified-id before 'do'" multiple times for every do{
}while(); loop I have... Any help?

Pastebin:http://pastebin.com/DubuAEUs

Comment: Perhaps you should cut down the amount of data you have (say, 3 pokemon and 7 moves) until you have working code.

Comment: I cut down the code as you said... Much easier to work with... Thanks!

Comment: From the code you posted, I would highly advise you to follow a C or C++ tutorial, as it seems quite obvious to me that you are new to C/C++ programming. There are a bunch of these on Internet.

Comment: The do whiles are outside setup or loop.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a general C/C++ programming problem. It is not specific to Arduino at all.

Comment: Moderators, please remove this question as the code in pastebin as expired so this question is pointless now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The do whiles are outside of the setup() or loop(), so they won't work.

I would suggest doing a simple C/C++ tutorial like [this one](http://www.learn-c.org) to get up to speed with how things work.